# Hasse diagram and table listing problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let P={n∈N|n divides 54} and let ⪯ be the partial order defined on p by

m ⪯ n ⟺ m divides n

a) draw the hasse diagram of (p, ⪯)

b) Make table listings glb(a,b) and lub(a,b) for all pairs (a,b) of elements in P. is (P,⪯) a lattice?

I am very stuck on this question in what should the hasse diagram look like. The only information given is that n divides by 54 but no integers are given? Does this just mean the multiples of 54 ie (54,108 ,162...) are the points? Also part b, what is meant here? I assume that they are making points for x and y?

Appreciate any help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

n divides 54 implies n is a non-negative integer.
The non-negative integers that divide 54 = 2×3×3×3 are
1. 2. 3, 6, 9, 18, 27, 54 which are the elements of P.
The glb and lub for P are the
greatest common factor and the least common multiple.